# What happens when my Dota Plus subscription ends?

Tags: dota-2

After the last patch in Dota 2, Valve added a new subscription-based upgrade called Dota Plus, where you have some quests and other stuff to do, such as leveling your heroes, or collecting points to buy some hero sets.

What will happen when my subscription ends?
If I renew it do I still have my points or levels on heroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy there is no statement of Valve about this situation.
I will edit my answer as soon as i know more.

Most probably your Progress on the Hero is frozen.

You **will** be able to:

- use unlocked chat-wheel phrases
- spend shards
- use relics you already have
- continue progressing after renewing the subscription

You **will not** be able to:

- use the plus ingame features (pick/lane/item-suggestions, etc.)
- complete quests
- earn new shards in any other way (except getting +400 for double randomed relics)
- make any hero level progress

Comment: This is mostly confirmed by https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/88k5yy/the_message_you_will_get_after_your_dota_expires/?utm_content=comments&utm_medium=hot&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=DotA2

Comment: I am able to do all of that even though my plus just expired yesterday